# backup SQL from localhost

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, localhost, backup

Hi I have done this page for the client to WordPress on localhost. I did a backup and I can not import a SQL database error pops up. All I have uploaded to the server. Now, only now I was ET database and I'm stuck here. Please help, I attach a screen.

[image]

I care about time, please and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto phpmyadmin select your database go to sql tab than go to import browse your name.sql file and press go..it will upload your file

Comment: so I know that, and that's what I'm doing, but it just pops up this error.

Comment: are you choosing database before selecting file

Comment: Yes i choose my .sql file

Comment: before choosing that u need to select database in which you want to create tables

Comment: When export i choose "Dodaj oświadczenie DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER" 

Now its done, Thank you all for help ! :)